# Make IE 8's javascript console give more info than "{...}" for objects

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to debug an issue that only seems to occur in IE 7 and 8, and the debugger's console is being utterly useless.

Any time I type in an expression that results in an object it just prints "{...}" to the console.  I need to inspect the returned object, but it gives me no easy way to do so.

Is there any way to get this to behave more like Chrome's debug tools or Firebug, both which let me actually inspect the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add a "watch expression" - in this way, it also displays the {...}, but it is expandable and you can see the internals of the object.

Answer (score 2):

get the new and much improved [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for IE.

Comment: Can that do things like break on exceptions?